# How to change topbar icon size?

Tags: elgg

elgg topbar icon. how to change size to 100px by defult  it is 16px
i tried lot of time but i didnt find any solution plz help me 
I am working on Elgg. I have one problem please help me.
after 2 full days I didn't find any proper solution plz help me in my Elgg I want to change the toolbar avatar image size to 100px how can I change the image size?

http://vijaypawar.com/new/activity
 this is link please suggest me thanks.
thanks in advance

Comment: are you using any theme or just default theme, what version are you using for elgg ?

Answer (score 0):

Topbar icon is registered as part of topbar menu here: https://github.com/Elgg/Elgg/blob/0fc935e3f8a9076d2579745d156e1e64112c16b5/engine/lib/users.php#L1107

Try unregistering old menu item and registering your version that uses 'medium' size (which is exactly 100px x 100px).